# Which animal's droppings are these?

Tags: identification, pests

I was tearing down my tool shed in the garden and found these droppings on the floor. Can someone tell me which animal's droppings are these?

Note: I live in the Pacific Northwest of the US

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell the size of them from  a picture, but they are rodent.  Either Mice or Rats.  How to Identify Rat Faeces?

Rat scat is often found in large groupings. They are about the size and shape of an a single peanut
Mice scat are much smaller than a single peanut. They are elongated and with a sharp end.

Know that you live in the PNW, I know there is a huge rat population.  But, these droppings appear to be to small for rats.  You might find nest in insulation or in the walls, these would be mice.  Rats tend to nest underground.  Your shed is a good place for a mouse to stay warm for the winter.  Rats can stay warmer underground.   If the shed is open to the outside in anyway.  Even a crack under the door you will get rodents.   If it's just the smallest of cracks then it's mice.  If it's a gap. Then you probably have had many rodent visitors of different species.

[Identifying Rat and Mice Visitors](https://www.bigbluebug.com/identifying-rodent-droppings)

Comment: I agree, I should have used object in the picture for scale. At least in the last picture there's half of a peanut shell (quite co-incidentally). We recently had our crawlspace inspected and they said there was evidence of mice before but not anymore. So it could be mice like you say. We also have a lot of squirrels in our backyard.

Comment: Not a squirrel.  Definitely not.  They might run in real quick to hide something, but they don't like to stay on the ground very long.  Not long enough to leave that mess.  But to be honest, I don't know anything about squirrel scat.